# TodayExtension UITableViewCell not appearing on 64-bits devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am working on an app that has a TodayExtension with a UITableView and some cells. The extension is working fine on older devices, it is however not working on newer devices/simulators. I think it might have something to do with the fact that they are 64-bits instead of 32-bits.

The exact problem I am having: the UITableViewCells are just not appearing, even though all the delegate methods are called. I printed them out and they behave exactly as expected. The UITableView is appearing on the Extension just not the cells.

Code:

```
-(LifestyleWidgetTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    LifestyleWidgetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"lifestyleTableViewCell"];

    [cell.widgetCollectionView reloadData];
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault];

    return cell;
}

-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 125;
}

-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[WidgetManager getInstance] getAllWidgetsOfType:LifestyleWidget].count + 1;
}
```

Even the size is adjusting as it should when adding more cells etc. Just no content is appearing... This has me completely stumped, if anyone can help me here it would be much appreciated.

(Yes I have arm64 in my build architectures in both the containing app and the extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out, on 64-bit devices it is an issue to return a float for the height of the TableViewCell instead of a CGFloat. The UITableViewCells ended up having a 0 height which made it seem like it isn't working. I always ignored the warning, my mistake.